# Is there any problem with the date column that I can't use timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas

Why I get the error in the below code:

there is a column and I want to implement Timestamp on it:

```py
df['date']


0       2014-09-04 00:00:00
1       2014-09-12 00:00:00
2       2014-09-04 00:00:00
3       2014-09-05 00:00:00
4       2014-09-06 00:00:00
               ...         
1049    2015-09-16 00:00:00
1050    2015-10-13 00:00:00
1051    2015-10-13 00:00:00
1052    2015-10-22 00:00:00
1053    2015-10-20 00:00:00
Name: date, Length: 1054, dtype: object

df['date']=df['date'].agg(pd.Timestamp)
```

Here is the given error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input
 [0       2014-09-04 00:00:00
1       2014-09-12 00:00:00
2       2014-09-04 00:00:00
3       2014-09-05 00:00:00
4       2014-09-06 00:00:00
               ...         
1049    2015-09-16 00:00:00
1050    2015-10-13 00:00:00
1051    2015-10-13 00:00:00
1052    2015-10-22 00:00:00
1053    2015-10-20 00:00:00
Name: date, Length: 1054, dtype: object] of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

Comment: *implement Timestamp* what do you mean by this exactly?

Comment: If use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` get `Timestamp`s.

Comment: I want to calculate the diffrence between all cells of this column and today. so, i used timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert `df['date']` to `datetime`, type of element in column is `str`.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: I run this code as well but i got error again, ```ValueError: day is out of range for month```

Comment: @hamideh, try this : `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')`

Comment: @hamideh, You can use also : `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='ignore')`, this code ignore errors.

Comment: great! that works !! now can I calculate the difference between this field and today?

Comment: @hamideh, this is another question, this better ask a new question, Are you wanting this : `pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - df['date']`

Comment: yes  I used your function and the last problem: ```df['Diff']=df['date'].agg(lambda x:pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()-x)``` TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Comment: @hamideh, before using your code add this line : `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])`

Comment: you mean this: ```df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='ignore')''' then this? ```df['Diff']=df['date'].agg(lambda x:pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()-x)'''

Comment: @hamideh, yes...

Comment: thats what i did. it doesn`t work ```TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Timestamp' and 'str```

Comment: @hamideh, i check, you dont' get any errors, this error because type of column `str` but if convert to datetime, you should not get any error.

Comment: I understand. this error is weird! I tried it several times.